# Como mostrar sinal de congruente (≡) no cmd

Tags: batch, caracteres

Eu tava tentando fazer um "design" com ascii no cmd mas sai esse conjunto de caracteres: "Ôëí", eu sei q é por causa das delimitação dos caracteres que o cmd pode mostrar e etc., mas podem me ajudar?

Comment: Creio que nem todos caracteres Unicode serão suportados em certas versões do Windows, mesmo que usando o comando `chcp 65001`, pode funcionar no Win10, mas não no Win8

Comment: ok, obrigado Guilherme

Comment: Depende da pagina de código. Algumas das páginas do DOS tem o simbolo "identical to", que é o `≡`. Na 437 é o 0xF0, mas na 850, normalmente usada em no brasil, o símbolo não está disponível.

Answer (score -1):

---

> 1) Baseado no comentário de **@Bacco**
>
> 2) Funciona no **Windows 10** & **Windows 8**
>
> 3) Não funciona no **Windows 7**

Para outros caráteres [consulte aqui](https://www.ascii-codes.com/)!!, depois é adicionar "**`0x`**" + código **`Hex`** do caractere, como no **`echo(0xF0`**: **`0x + HEX`**

---

```bat
@echo off & chcp 437 2>nul >nul 
for /f "delims= " %%c in ('forFiles /p "." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0xF0"
') do set "_con=%%c" & cmd /v /r echo/ && echo/ Como mostrar sinal de congruente %_con%
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!